# Does Cardano has flash loans DeFi?

Tags: defi

Does Cardano has flash loans implemented? Are they available in production?

If not: are there potential problems with eUTxO model, preventing their usage?

Answer (score 1):

The only information I could find is https://www.essentialcardano.io/glossary/flash-loan .